# Найти количество чётных цифр в записи числа отличных от нуля

Tags: c++

Дано целое число n. Требуется найти количество четных цифр в записи этого числа отличных от нуля.

Хотелось бы услышать от Вас, как мне реализовать данную программу.

Вот мои наработки:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a, b = 0, c = 0;
    cin >> a;
    if (a % 2 == 0) {
        b = b + 1;
    } else {
        b = b + 0;
    }
    if (a / 10 % 2 == 0) {
        c = c + 1;
    } else {
        c = c + 0;
    }
    cout << b + c;
    return 0;
}
```

а вот пример входных данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]>

Comment: Приведите примеры входных данных и результатов.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас как минимум не сработает для многозначного числа типа 1240152136... Увы, нет времени постепенно подталкивать вас к самостоятельному решению, так что посмотрите на этот код и постарайтесь понять, как он работает.

```
unsigned int evens(unsigned int n)
{
    int total = 0;
    for(;n;n/=10)
        if (n%2 == 0 && n%10) ++total;
    return total;
}
```